# Android get byteValue from Bluetooth data

Tags: android, arrays, bluetooth-lowenergy

When reading a Bluetooth sensor characteristic, the value or the measurement is stored in the characteristic value.  how can I get the byte value as such:

```
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
```

from the sensor value?

/************  EDIT  ***************/

@Vikram Recommends the following:

```
        private void updateAdc3Values(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

        // Convert values if needed
        //double adc3 = SensorTagData.extractAdc3(characteristic);


/******** Used to get raw HEX value ********/   

        byte[] ADCValue3 = characteristic.getValue();
        String adc3Hex = ADCValue3.toString()
                .replace("[", "")   //remove the right bracket
                .replace("]", ""); //remove the left bracket

//      Log.e("ADC3", "ADC CH3 characteristicvalue from TEST is " + adc3Hex);
//      Log.i("ADC3", "ADC Last 6CH3 characteristicvalue from TEST is " + adc3Hex.substring(adc3Hex.length() - 6));  //Prints last 6 of this string

        // Get UUID
        String ch3 = (String.valueOf(characteristic.getUuid()));
        String ch3UUID = ch3.substring(0, Math.min(ch3.length(), 8));
//      Log.d("ADC3", "ADC FIRST 6CH3 characteristicvalue from TEST is " + ch3.substring(0, Math.min(ch3.length(), 8)));  //Print first 6 of this string


        String adc3hex6 = adc3Hex.substring(adc3Hex.length() - 6);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        for (byte b : ADCValue3) { 
            if (sb.length() > 0) { 
                sb.append(':'); 
                } 
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b)); }


        Log.w("ADC3", "StringBuilder " + sb);

/********  Used to get raw HEX value   ********/        


    }
```

I have basically been using different types of output, to experiment with all of the possibilities. Using the byte[] characteristic value I am forming different types of output.  Disregard the UUID, this is us just proving that the values are coming from the correct channel.  So I just cut up the UUID to get the first 6 char which proves the channel it is coming from.

In the case above, the Log.i starting with ADC3 Byte Array Value, this line logs in one measurement a value of:

```
B@42bc0738
```

Then the sister log which follows after the StringBuilder is logging:

```
7a:17:d0:7f:ff:ff:21:b4:e1:80:00:00:a4:a6:f4:77:73:5e
```

This does appear to be the correct format and value that I am looking for.  Now it will be time to compare the values.

Comment: Why are you clowns downvoting this?  If you do not know the answer or do not understand it, then move on. But dont downvote it because yyou have no clue....  THis has nothing to do with what I have already tried.  The proper answer for this is goign to be an output format of some sort or a questions or value which I am not querying. If I knew what that was, I would not have to ask, now would I.

Comment: So, you are already able to obtain the `byte[]` from an instance of `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` using the `getValue()` method... you just need to format it as above?

Comment: yes I get the byte value but it comes out as [B@421234  But in previous applications such as the Texas Instruments, they have a string formated as so above.  Turns out that is the string I need to be able to reduce it to a 24 bit value.

Comment: No, you're not printing the byte array correctly. The `[` indicates type `array` - `B` stands for byte - `@` is I think the separator - `421234` is the hashcode. Try printing the array like this: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); for (byte b : byteArray) { if (sb.length() > 0) { sb.append(':'); } sb.append(String.format("%02x", b)); }`. After this, check the value of `sb.toString()`.

Comment: Thank you.  This does appear to be the answer.  Please add your string builder code below as an answer so that I may mark it appropriately.  You can just copy the code above and paste it if you like.  I have already explained everything around the code.  Thank you very much for your time and thought which you have put into helping me. Even though it is what this site is about, you have still chosen to take on the task yourself.

Comment: You are very welcome and thank you for the kind words. I have added an answer below. Please let me know if its lacking in any manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transferring from comments:

OP is obtaining the `byte[]` from `BluetoothGattCharacteristic#getValue()` method.

To format the code in the required format, use the following snippet:

```
// Use StringBuilder so that we can go through the byte[] 
// and append formatted text
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

for (byte b : byteArray) { 
    if (sb.length() > 0) { 
        sb.append(':'); 
    } 

    sb.append(String.format("%02x", b)); 
}
```